# How may I forbid calls to const member function of an rvalue object in C++ 2011?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, deleted-functions

The following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string const& at(std::vector<std::string> const& n, int i)
{
    return n[i];
}

std::vector<std::string> mkvec()
{
    std::vector<std::string> n;
    n.push_back("kagami");
    n.push_back("misao");
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::string const& s = at(mkvec(), 0);
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // D'oh!
    return 0;
}
```

may lead to crash because the original vector is already destructed there. In C++ 2011 (c++0x) after rvalue-reference is introduced in, a **deleted function** declaration can be used to completely forbid calls to `at` if the vector argument is an rvalue

```
std::string const& at(std::vector<std::string>&&, int) = delete;
```

That looks good, but the following code still cause crash

```
int main()
{
    std::string const& s = mkvec()[0];
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // D'oh!
    return 0;
}
```

because calls to member function `operator [] (size_type) const` of an rvalue object is still allowed. Is there any way can I forbid this kind of calls?

FIX:

The examples above is not what I did in real projects. I just wonder if C++ 2011 support any member function qualifying like

```
class A {
    void func() rvalue; // Then a call on an rvalue object goes to this overload
    void func() const;
};
```

FIX:

It's great, but I think C++ standard goes too far at this feature. Anyway, I have following code compiled on clang++ 2.9

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    A() {}

    void func() &
    {
        puts("a");
    }

    void func() &&
    {
        puts("b");
    }

    void func() const &
    {
        puts("c");
    }
};

int main()
{
    A().func();
    A a;
    a.func();
    A const b;
    b.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and you shouldn't. How am I to do `std::cout << at(mkvec(), 0) << std::endl;`, a perfectly reasonable thing, if you've banned me from using `at()` on temporaries?

Storing references to temporaries is just a problem C++ programmers have to deal with, unfortunately.

---

To answer your new question, yes, you can do this:

```
class A {
    void func() &; // lvalues go to this one
    void func() &&; // rvalues go to this one
};

A a;
a.func(); // first overload

A().func(); // second overload
```

Comment: I've always found this reference binding appalling. It must have been a good idea to begin with, and sure comes handy at times, but its potential of destruction is incredible and even careful code inspection may fail to detect it... :/

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but I got compile errors on g++ 4.6.0. Can you tell me which compiler can deal with that?

Comment: If you make the `func` overloads public, recent builds of clang will handle this example.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. `void func() &;`... I can guess the intention, but I think I missed a point in the standard here. Trailing `&` after a method definition...? I have to look that one up. Ok, I found it! Amazing...

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea:

To disable copying constructor on the vector somehow.

```
vector ( const vector<T,Allocator>& x );
```

Implicit copying of arrays is not that good thing anyway. (wondering why STL authors decided to define such ctor at all)

It will fix problems like you've mentioned and as a bonus will force you to use more effective version of your function:

```
void mkvec(std::vector<std::string>& n)
{
    n.push_back("kagami");
    n.push_back("misao");
}
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting he modifies his standard library to make vector non-copy-constructable?  Or am I misreading you?  Because that is the silliest suggestion I have ever heard.

Comment: Your version of `mkvec` isn't necessarily more efficient, lookup RVO.

Comment: The function `mkvec()` is perfectly fine, yes! Thanks to **Return-Value-Optimization**, and in C++0x even more, thanks to RValues, yes. Please yes, write code like this, it is RAII, concise, safe and fast. But, of course `string &s = mkvec()[0]` explodes, thats correct. You named it right `mk...` **makes** something. Don't get a ref on something you just *made* -- that is the issue. If you would have called it `getvec()`, *then* I would expect `string&s=getvec()[0]` to be ok. But `string&s=mkvec()[0]` is allowd to fail :-)